# append value to list within loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am running through a column and storing the value for each row in a dictionary. 
if the value does not exists i want to add a cell value on that row to an array/list. In the end i want a sum of all the values in the array. 
How do i append the values to an array and sum the values in the array? I hope someone can help

**Code**

```
Const NETSCONT_SHT3 = "D"
Const NETSCONT_SHT4 = "I"
Const NETSEXP_SHT4 = "H"
Const MEMBER_SHT4 = "G"


Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow, iTargetRow As Long, iCopyRow As Long, NbCont_SHT3 As Long, AmCont_SHT3 As Double
Dim NbCont_SHT4 As Long, AmCont_SHT4 As Double, NbResults As Integer, AmResult As Double, pct_change As Double
Dim msg As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim count As Long, countWB As Integer
Dim WkSht_Src   As Worksheet
Dim WkBk_Dest   As Workbook
Dim WkSht_Dest  As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim d As Long, dE As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("BrokerSelect")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("ContributionSplitReport")
Set ws4 = wb.Sheets("ContributionExceptionReport")

Dim dict As Object, dictEXP As Object, dictRESULTP As Object, dictRESULTN As Object, dictMEMBER As Object, sKey As Double, ar As Variant
Dim sEXP As Double, sRESP As Double, sRESN As Double, sMEMBER As Integer, arEXP As Variant, arRESP As Variant, arRESN As Variant, arMEMBER As Variant


Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictEXP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictRESULTP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictRESULTN = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictMEMBER = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")



iLastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.count, MEMBER_SHT4).End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = 18 To iLastRow
sMEMBER = ws4.Cells(iRow, MEMBER_SHT4) ' column "G"
sKey = ws4.Cells(iRow, NETSCONT_SHT4) ' column "I"
sEXP = ws4.Cells(iRow, NETSEXP_SHT4) ' column "H"

If dictMEMBER.exists(sMEMBER) Then
    dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) = dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) & ";" & iRow

Else
    dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) = iRow

        If sKey <> "0" Then
            pct_change = (sKey - sEXP) / sKey
        If pct_change > 0 Then
            dictRESULTP.Add d, pct_change: d = d + 1
        ElseIf pct_change < 0 Then
            dictRESULTN.Add dE, pct_change: dE = dE + 1
        End If
      End If
        'If dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) does not exist I want to append the cell value (irow, i) into an array.
        'In the end i want to sum the value of the array

End If 
next
```

Comment: When you say, you want the sum of all the values from your Array, are the entry in the Array Summable? Aren't they text?

Comment: If you can describe as well all the columns of the Array and its datatype in your Question then it would be very helpful

Comment: The values i want to insert in the array are doubles. So it should be fine i think

Comment: You say the Values are **Double** but `dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) = dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) & ";" & iRow` this is showing that you are adding text to it, so I'm confused

Comment: The values i want to append are values in a different column. I use the dictionary dictMEMBER to store the values from a column. If the key of that dictionary is unique, I want to append a different column value to an array. I hope this makes sense

Comment: So `DicMEMBER` is an Array of what type please? And `DicRESULTN` is an Array of what? Could you update your question to include the composition of both Arrays please?

Comment: dict* are all dictionaries. I do not have an array yet. I want to create some kind of array/list where i can store values.

Comment: Great, could you tell me here all the Columns you want to have inside of each dictionary? I mean `dictMEMBER` and `DictRESULTN`?

Comment: Seeing some sample data would be helpful here

Comment: It would be great to get the values from column "i" and the values from column "H". Are storing the values in a dictionary that is already created? because i use the dictMEMBER to find the unique values from column "G".  is that a problem for storing it in the same dictionary?

Comment: @RyanWildry i will update question

Comment: Thanks @RyanWildry, now it's clearer

Comment: Add a screenshot of the output you are trying to achieve from the sample data shown,

Comment: @CDP1802 not sure what you want. If you look at the scrren shot i have posted i want to add the values of column H for every member number. if you look at member 80, it is important that only the first value "H18" are picked. The next value should then be member 40 and the amount in "H21". I hope this makes sense

Comment: So for the sample shown the result you want is 40,277.19. What are the pct_change calcs for, is that code unrelated to your question ? Do you need an array, why not just add to a sum the first value found as you scan down.

Comment: I need the pct_change to find out if the total amount is bigger or smaller than the expected amount. And i am not sure how to sum all of the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear about what you wish to achieve but the code below will do most of it. Please try it.

```
Sub Benchmark()
    ' This proc needs a reference to 'Miscrosoft Scripting Runtime'
    ' If you use late binding VBA will do without the reference but you
    ' won't have the benefit of Intellisense drop-downs while programming.
    ' Checkmark: Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime'

    Const ConExMember = "G"
    Const ConExExp = "H"
    Const ConExAct = "I"


    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim WsConEx As Worksheet
    Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Member As String
    Dim Expected As Double, Actual As Double
    Dim ChangePct As Double
    Dim Rl As Long                                  ' last row
    Dim R As Long                                   ' rows loop counter
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    Dim Msg As String, Count(2) As Integer

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set WsConEx = Wb.Sheets("ContributionExceptionReport")
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' pct change in expected and actual cont
    With WsConEx
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ConExMember).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 18 To Rl
            Member = .Cells(R, ConExMember).Value
            Actual = Val(.Cells(R, ConExAct).Value)
            Expected = Val(.Cells(R, ConExExp).Value)
            On Error Resume Next            ' if Actual = 0
            ChangePct = (Actual - Expected) / Actual
            If Err.Number Then ChangePct = 0

            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not Dict.Exists(Member) Then
                Dict.Add Member, ChangePct
            End If
        Next R
    End With

    ChangePct = 0
    For Each Tmp In Dict.Keys
        ChangePct = ChangePct + Dict(Tmp)
        R = Sgn(Dict(Tmp)) + 1
        Count(R) = Count(R) + 1
    Next Tmp

    Msg = "Members:     " & Dict.Count & vbCr & _
          "Increases:      " & Count(2) & vbCr & _
          "Decreases:     " & Count(1) & vbCr & _
          "Unchanged:  " & Count(0) & vbCr & _
          "Change % :  " & Round(ChangePct * 100, 2) & "%"
    MsgBox Msg, vbInformation, "Summary"
End Sub
```

The code will loop through all your members in what was your Ws4. It will skip over duplicates. Unique members will be added to a dictionary with their names (or perhaps ID numbers) as Key and the percentage of change as `Item`. The result will be one dictionary with all unique names and all the changes.

In the second half of the code this dictionary is examined. Changes are sorted into positive, negative and unchanged and counted for each category. The aggregate change is calculated and the members counted. All of that goes into a message box.

The important change I made is to create pairs of data, with the member ID as key and the change as related information. This data can be evaluated easily, with very few lines of code, whichever way you want.

Comment: This seems very useful and not as overwhelming as my initial code. Thank you! But is it possible to get the total from column "H" and "i" for the NOT duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: Don't understand. Duplicate IDs are ignored. So, my code already gets the totals only for non-duplicates. However, I point out that the first occurrence will be recorded, further ones ignored. If both entries were not identical in columns H:I the resulting evaluation must be flawed.

Answer (score 0):

I update the code as following hoping it would be helpful to you:

```
Sub AddAndSumMissingDictionary()
'Constants
Const NETSCONT_SHT3 = "D"
Const NETSEXP_SHT4 = "H"
Const NETSCONT_SHT4 = "I"
Const MEMBER_SHT4 = "G"

'ArrayColumns
Const cTotalExpected = 0
Const cTotalNets = 1
Const cTotalNetSplitAVC = 2

'Workbooks & Worksheets
Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
Dim WkSht_Src   As Worksheet
Dim WkBk_Dest   As Workbook
Dim WkSht_Dest  As Worksheet

'Array you Requested
Dim ArrMissingDictionary() As Double
Dim lMissingDictCount As Long

'Iteration Rows & Ranges
Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, iTargetRow As Long, iCopyRow As Long, NbCont_SHT3 As Long, AmCont_SHT3 As Double
Dim NbCont_SHT4 As Long, AmCont_SHT4 As Double, NbResults As Integer, AmResult As Double, pct_change As Double
Dim msg As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim count As Long, countWB As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim d As Long, dE As Long

'Initializing Variables
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("BrokerSelect")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("ContributionSplitReport")
Set ws4 = wb.Sheets("ContributionExceptionReport")

Dim dict As Object, dictEXP As Object, dictRESULTP As Object, dictRESULTN As Object, dictMEMBER As Object, sKey As Double, ar As Variant
Dim sEXP As Double, sRESP As Double, sRESN As Double, sMEMBER As Integer, arEXP As Variant, arRESP As Variant, arRESN As Variant, arMEMBER As Variant

'Initializing Dictionaries
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictEXP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictRESULTP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictRESULTN = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dictMEMBER = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Set Missing lMissingDictCount to 0
lMissingDictCount = 0

'Get the Last Row
iLastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.count, MEMBER_SHT4).End(xlUp).Row

'Iteration Process
For iRow = 18 To iLastRow
    sMEMBER = ws4.Cells(iRow, MEMBER_SHT4) ' column "G"
    sKey = ws4.Cells(iRow, NETSCONT_SHT4) ' column "I"
    sEXP = ws4.Cells(iRow, NETSEXP_SHT4) ' column "H"

    'Checking Existance of Dictionary Entry
    If dictMEMBER.exists(sMEMBER) Then
        'I think this should be like this
        dictMEMBER.Key(sMEMBER) = dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) & ";" & iRow  'dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) = dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) & ";" & iRow

    Else
        dictMEMBER.Key(sMEMBER) = iRow  'dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) = iRow

            If sKey <> "0" Then
                pct_change = (sKey - sEXP) / sKey
            If pct_change > 0 Then
                dictRESULTP.Add d, pct_change: d = d + 1
            ElseIf pct_change < 0 Then
                dictRESULTN.Add dE, pct_change: dE = dE + 1
            End If
          End If

        'Increment lMissingDictCount
        lMissingDictCount = lMissingDictCount + 1 'UBound(ArrMissingDictionary, 1) + 1

        'Adding the Array:
        ReDim Preserve ArrMissingDictionary(2, lMissingDictCount)  'Increasing the Array Row while keeping its content
        ArrMissingDictionary(cTotalExpected, lMissingDictCount) = ws4.Cells(iRow, NETSEXP_SHT4)
        ArrMissingDictionary(cTotalNets, lMissingDictCount) = ws4.Cells(iRow, NETSCONT_SHT4)
        ArrMissingDictionary(cTotalNetSplitAVC, lMissingDictCount) = ws4.Cells(iRow, MEMBER_SHT4)

            'If dictMEMBER(sMEMBER) does not exist I want to append the cell value (irow, i) into an array.
    End If
Next iRow

'In the end i want to sum the value of the array
'I'm reusing the iRow again
Dim dTotalExpected As Double, dTotalNets As Double, dTotalNetSplitAVC As Double

For iRow = LBound(ArrMissingDictionary, 1) To UBound(ArrMissingDictionary, 1)
    dTotalExpected = dTotalExpected + ArrMissingDictionary(cTotalExpected, iRow)           'Sum Missing on Col "H"
    dTotalNets = dTotalNets + ArrMissingDictionary(cTotalNets, iRow)                       'Sum Missing on Col "I"
    dTotalNetSplitAVC = dTotalNetSplitAVC + ArrMissingDictionary(cTotalNetSplitAVC, iRow)  'Sum Missing on Col "G"
Next iRow

'You can affect the dTotalExpected, dTotalNets and dTotalNetSplitAVC for your purpose
End Sub
```

Hopefully, this will solve your issue

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However i do get some error at the "adding the array:" part. The redim line comes with error: array already dimensioned. The next lines have a subscript out of range error. Can you help me out?

Comment: Ok, you can change the `Dim ArrMissingDictionary(0, 3) As Double` to be `Dim ArrMissingDictionary(0, 0) As Double` so it forces the declaration to Redimension the Array everytime the `ReDim preserve` part is called

Comment: Please try that and let me know so I could update my Answer

Comment: Sorry, my bet, kindly change the Array Declaration to be `Dim ArrMissingDictionary() As Double` and let's see

Comment: So it seems to work for the first 3 loops. so for member 80. But as soon as i try to run it on loop 4, i get the subscript out of range. (I use F8 to run through each line)

Comment: I just updated the Script in the Answer. May you please try it? I think I made mistakes in the Columns of the Array as VBA is **Base 0** so `ArrMissingDictionary(0, 0)` is Column 1, `ArrMissingDictionary(0, 1)` is Column 2 and `ArrMissingDictionary(0, 2)` is Column 3

Comment: I changed as well the Values of the `Const cTotalExpected = 0`,
`Const cTotalNets = 1` and
`Const cTotalNetSplitAVC = 2`

Comment: Now i get an error at "lMissingDictCount = UBound(ArrMissingDictionary, 1) + 1" subscript out of range

Comment: You can change it back to `lMissingDictCount = lMissingDictCount + 1`

Comment: I get the same error as before but strangely the error happens one loop after now.

Comment: @lass9509, kindly try the Function now. My mistake was I exchanged the Column and Rows in the Array `ArrMissingDictionary(Column, Row)` and I tested it so it should be working for you now

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Unfortunately i can only mark one answer as solution/most helpful. The solution from @variatus was closest to the answer i was seeking. Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: No problem, that's why we are here. I hope when your reputation grows you would assist others like us as well :)